# Check if the string contains all the characters from a to z

Tags: c#

I have to write a C# code to check if a string contains all the alphabets from a to z ."this is a test" (without quotes). It doesn't contain all alphabets from a to z so the  output is no. 
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". It contains all alphabets from a to z so the  output is yes.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is it that you want? Do you tried looping through all the characters?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a [perfect question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Also, be sure to take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Try it! If you get stuck (which I don't see why) we'll help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extension method like this

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static char[] _alphabet;

    static StringExtensions()
    {
        _alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    }

    public static bool ContainsAlphabet(this string input)
    {
        return !_alphabet
            .Except(new HashSet<char>(input))
            .Any();
    }
}

"asdasd".ContainsAlphabet(); //false
"abcdeffffghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzz".ContainsAlphabet(); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach it, initialise an array containing every letter:

```
char[] letters = new []{"a","b","c"...};
```

Then initialise a list to hold all of the letters present in your string:

```
List<char> lettersInString = new List<char>();
```

Now loop through your string adding distinct letters:

```
foreach (char letter in myString){if (!lettersInString.Contains(char)){lettersInString.Add(char);}}
```

Finally, see if the list contains every letter:

```
if (letters.All(letter=>lettersInString.Contains(letter)){DoSomething();}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: You forgot the `new` in your array creation.

Comment: My mistake, good spot

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with `HashSet`s:

```
bool HasAllLeters(string input) 
{
    var lettersInInput = new HashSet<char>(input); // or `input.ToLower()` for case insensitiveness
    var alphabet = new HashSet<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"); // you can actually store this as a `private static readonly` field for performance 
    return alphabet.IsSubsetOf(lettersInInput);
}
```

I used `IsSubsetOf` and not `Equals` because the input may contain characters that are not letters, like punctuation.

*Edit*: I just noticed that `input.ToLower()` allocates a whole string. So use `input.Select(ch => char.ToLower(ch))` instead.